# How to implement str.partition but for regexes

Tags: python

`str.partition` has the following functionality which is often quite useful for parsing strings.  I'd like the same functionality but extended to python `re.compile(...)` objects.

#### when the string is contained

```
>>> 'foo bar baz'.partition('bar')
('foo ', 'bar', ' baz')
>>> 'foo bar bar baz'.partition('bar')
('foo ', 'bar', ' bar baz')
```

#### when the string is not contained

```
>>> 'foo bar baz'.partition('hi')
('foo bar baz', '', '')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution, plus a bonus `rpartition`:

```
def re_partition(regex, s):
    match = regex.search(s)
    if match:
        return s[:match.start()], s[slice(*match.span())], s[match.end():]
    else:
        return (s, '', '')

def re_rpartition(regex, s):
    # find the last match, or None if not found
    match = None
    for match in regex.finditer(s):
        pass
    if match:
        return s[:match.start()], s[slice(*match.span())], s[match.end():]
    else:
        return ('', '', s)
```

They both work by utilizing the resulting `match` object to slice the original string.